# TypeScript errors while editing JavaScript file in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Just out of the blue, I've been experiencing weird TypeScript errors in my pure JavaScript files. I don't use TypeScript at all, so I have no idea where this came from. Perhaps I mashed my keyboard and something was enabled? Not sure.

Things to note:

- Nothing referring to TypeScript in my User preferences
- The language mode is JavaScript

For example, I'm receiving an error `[ts] '$var1' is declared but its value is never read.` on hover of a variable that has been declared, just not referenced. It also washes out the variable color, which is quite annoying.

[image: Two variables. One referenced]
[image: The hover error message]

Here are the extensions I'm using:

- Debugger for Chrome
- Document This
- One Dark Pro
- PHP DocBlocker
- PHP IntelliSense
- phpfmt - PHP formatter
- SCSS IntelliSense
- WordPress Snippet

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. This is a minor issue, but it's really annoying.

Comment: What extensions do you have enabled?

Comment: @J.Pichardo Knew I was leaving out something. I've just edited the post with the extensions I am using.

Comment: Are you positive that's a typescript error? That's a somewhat standard javascript notice that any decent IDE would show as well....

Comment: Seconding @cale_b, this is helpful if anything IMO.  The declaration as type `any` seems typescripty but this is what I would expect a half decent IDE to do. Check the release notes as well.

Comment: @Phix Wow, I feel like a total fool. It's right there in the release notes. Just didn't expect it I guess. For anyone curious this seems to be a new update in VS Code "Highlight unused variables and imports" https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_highlight-unused-variables-and-imports

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this seems to be an update to VS Code "Highlight unused variables and imports".

Here is more info about this release and feature in particular:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_highlight-unused-variables-and-imports